# making a grammar ll(1) and unambiguous

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I have a CFG in the form

```
PB := PB | R | R
R := s
```

I have tried to make it ll(1) by removing the left recursion resulting in

```
 PB := R PB' | R PB'
 PB' := PB'| ϵ
 R := s
```

However, I believe, removing the left recursion is making the grammar now ambiguous.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original grammar is ambiguous. Elimination of left-recursion neither creates nor removes ambiguity.

Ambiguities:

```
PB := PB
```

This production does nothing, but it can be applied any number of times

```
PB := R
PB := R
```

These two productions are identical, so anywhere one might apply, the other one might be used instead.

When you remove the pointless productions, you are left with

```
PB := R
R := s
```

Which is unambiguous and non-recursive. Since it is not recursive, there is no left recursion to remove.